# Is it possible to import ArcPy module to PyPy interpreter?

Tags: python, arcpy, installation

I'm trying to use PyPy for my code because of speed, but my code needs ArcPy module to run and I can't find out how to install or import this module to ArcPy. I'm using PyPy 2.3, Python 2.7 and Win 7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried other ways of speeding your code up in vanilla CPython like profiling it, or using numpy and [numba](http://numba.pydata.org)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to import arcpy in PyPy. The required libraries have not been compiled against PyPy's CPython-like API that would enable compatibility.